# How to tell if Menu(Not menu item) is clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout

for menu item I know I can use onOptionsSelected, but what function do I use if I want to know when the menu itself is clicked? (the 3 dots showed in the image below).

[image: toolbar]

Comment: set Onclick listener!

Comment: @Xenolion What do I set the onClick listener to listen for? Could you show how it is done for Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to set click `listener` to menu. Just `override` the following methods.

```
//Called on you open menu. or when you click on menu the three dots.
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return true;
}
```

You can also override this to detect close:

```
// Called when you close (ie. by clicking outside etc)
@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Are these built-in methods? It seems android studio cannot find them.

Comment: Where do I call these methods?

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar Yes they will be called by the framework

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar Just like you override `onOptionsSelected`, `onCreate` etc, inside activity. You don't need to call them, the framework will call them, you just need to override.

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar BTW `onMenuOpened` will be called two times, first time menu will be null, so check for null like `if (menu != null) { doLogic();} else {doNothing();}`